# How can I use XML to store and retrieve data?

Tags: xml, firefox-addon

I am creating an extension for Firefox which transliterates a given web page. So I wanted to know how I am going to send the webpage to the server and get it back transliterated using xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML doesn't do this. XML only defines its contents. To send/receive XML over the wire, you need to use javascript and a server side language. XSL can sometimes help in this.

Comment: ok so how am i supposed to send the request and get the transliterated web page!! i m a little confused with this!! can u plz help me!!